# I want to web crawl, but some items are crawled, but some items are not crawled. I do not know the cause

Tags: python, web-crawler

I'm using BeautifulSoup in python, to scrape a website.

While the `addrs`, `a_earths` was crawled, `points = soup.select('.addr_point')` at the end This section can't be crawled. I don't know the cause (the dashed red box in [Image of webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gGvOV.jpg))

Following is code block I'm using:

```
import urllib.parse
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

url = 'http://www.dooinauction.com/auction/ca_list.php'

req = urllib.request.Request(url) #
html = urllib.request.urlopen(req).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser') 

tots = soup.select('div.title_left font') #total
tot = int(re.findall('\d+', tots[0].text)[0]) 
print(f'total : {tot}건')

url = f'http://www.dooinauction.com/auction/ca_list.php?total_record={tot}&search_fm_off=1&search_fm_off=1&start=0'
html = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

addrs = soup.select('.addr')  # crawling OK
a_earths = soup.select('.list_class.bold') #crawling OK
points = soup.select('.addr_point') #crawling NO
print()
```

[Image of webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gGvOV.jpg)

Comment: I couldnt access `http://www.dooinauction.com/auction/ca_list.php`, that kinda hard to tell the problem. Does this website have restriction?

Comment: Sorry. I need to register

Comment: Hi, how do you know it cant be crawled, could you print the result, is it None, does it throw back error etc... would help others to answer your question

Comment: I checked while debugging and found that it didn't crawl. As others said, I think you need to log in. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I browse your website and it seems that I can't see the addr_points section. I think maybe this is the reason.

Screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: If you do not log in, you will not see some information. I always log in ahead of time. It doesn't seem to be due to a login problem. Thank you.

Comment: If you need to log in first to see those information. Then I think you need to include the cookies when you crawl the data. Otherwise the data won't be crawled